# Android Design spec for listview looks wrong

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a listview inside a navigation drawer, and I am consulting the design spec set out by Android (https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs)

My list items have two lines of text:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/note"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

All the dimensions are according to the spec.

Here is a screenshot, as you can see, the 2nd line is cut off.

[image]

Any ideas why, when using the guideline specs, it's wrong?

Comment: That's odd, I tried the layout code and it looks just fine. You also followed Material Design standards as written, so I don't really know what to say! I can only think of a little hack, but I won't post it as an answer: set android:layout_height="wrap_content" in your LinearLayout and then add android:min_height="72dp"; I'm afraid it is not the answer you were expecting, but you can try this until someone comes up with a better one :)

Comment: Have you tried turning on `Show layout bounds` in the developer options to see if that shows anything useful?

Comment: are you using roboto for the texts? Can it be because of the default font( i think you are using) ?

Comment: @VamsiChalla I have not selected any font family, as you can see in my layout XML, so I assume it is using Roboto or my system default (on CM12s, default font, so maybe Roboto?)

Comment: @HexAndBugs Is that on my phone? Or in Android Studio?

Comment: On the phone - _Settings > Developer options > Show layout bounds_ (which is under the _Drawing_ heading).

Comment: I wonder if it could be to do with font padding meaning your `TextView`s are both slightly taller than the size you specified. You could try setting `android:includeFontPadding="false"` on both your `TextView`s and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `LinearLayout`, remove `android:paddingTop` and `android:paddingBottom`, and use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` instead.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <TextView ... />

    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm, this does work, but it seems "hacky". Any idea why my layout doesn't work when the dimensions seem fine?

Comment: @MrPablo You've specified a fixed height for the row (72dp) and fixed padding on top and bottom (20dp each). That leaves only 32dp left to place any content, which is clearly not enough for the content you have and results in clipping. What I posted will center the contents of the row view always, so there's equal space at the top and bottom. If anything, I would argue that using padding to try to achieve the same effect is "hacky".

Comment: I'm guessing sp units are different in size to dp? Because the fonts should only take up 30sp(dp?) combined...